# React-Native-Paper surface component not loading

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have a component that loads into my app, however I can't get the Surface component to load.  The text inside it renders fine, however the parent Surface component does not.  It also does not appear in the inspector

My component is below.  Any ideas?

```
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {Surface, Text} from 'react-native-paper';

function UpComing({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 15}}>Upcoming Classes</Text>
      <Surface styles={styles.surface}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </Surface>
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  surface: {
    padding: 8,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    elevation: 4,
  },
});

export default UpComing;
```

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?